# Converting rows to column R

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert some order details in R. I have the data as below:

```
Order ID   Product Name
1          A
1          B
1          C
2          E
2          F
2          D
```

And I need to convert this to as below:

```
Order ID   Product Name 1   Product Name 2   Product name 3
1          A                B                C
2          E                F                D
```

The examples I can see in the forum deal with 3 variables. Mine has just 2 variables. I've tried reshape in my data. Doesn't seem to get the desired output.

Comment: @akrun The examples I can see in the forum deal with 3 variables. Mine has just 2 variables. I've tried reshape in my data. Doesn't seem to get the desired output.

Comment: You need a sequence `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(df1), Order_ID ~ paste0("Product_Name", rowid(Order_ID)), value.var = "Product_Name")`  I am sure that there are dupes for this

Comment: akrun , Jogo:  It worked! Thanks!